# How to write a unit test for datetime functions

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, datetime

I have the following function below that returns the time as `00:00:00`.
How can I write a unit test to verify this works?

```
def get_date() -> datetime:
    return datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.min.time())
print(get_date())
```

Comment: Are you asking how to examine the return value, or asking how to write a unit test using a specific framework (`pytest`, `unittest`, etc)?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation to see how to retrieve the time from an instance of `datetime`? You just need to do that, and compare it to a know time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things here:

1. Convert the datetime object to a string and assert against it:

   ```
   assertEqual("00:00:00", get_date().time().isoformat())
   ```

   and If you want to assert against date:

   ```
   assertEqual(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), get_date().date().isoformat())
   ```
2. Directly assert datetime objects:

   ```
   assertEqual(datetime.min.time(), get_date().time())  
   assertEqual(datetime.today().date(), get_date().date())
   ```